# Cannot dynamic_cast sideways

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I stumbled upon casting sideways from derived to derived class and discovered a gap in my knowledge. I had been living in a world where this is possible - until now. Instead, `std::bad_cast` is thrown. What's going on here?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
protected:
    int x_;

public:
    Base(int x) : x_(x) {}
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    int x() const { return x_; }
    virtual void setX(int x) = 0;
};

class Editable : public Base // class implements setters
{
public:
    Editable(int x) : Base(x) {}
    void setX(int x) { x_ = x; }
};

class ReadOnly : public Base // class implements empty setters
{
public:
    ReadOnly(int x) : Base(x) {}
    void setX(int x) {}
};

int main()
{
    Editable editable(4);
    ReadOnly &readOnly = dynamic_cast<ReadOnly&>(editable); // std::bad_cast
}
```

Comment: Sure, it can cast sideways (though it's not really in the sense you are using), but the thing you are casting must still actually be a `ReadOnly` (or a class derived from it)...

Comment: "Unlike other casts, a dynamic_cast involves a run-time type check. If the object bound to the pointer is not an object of the target type, it fails and the value is 0. If it's a reference type when it fails, then an exception of type bad_cast is thrown."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what is meant when people say that `dynamic_cast` can cast sideways:

```
struct A { virtual ~A() = default; };
struct B { virtual ~B() = default; };
struct D : A, B {};

B* pb = new D();
A* pa = dynamic_cast<A*>(pb); // OK
```

i.e., it allows you to cast a `B*` to a `A*` if the pointer is pointing to something that's derived from both `A` and `B`. For the cast to succeed, there still must be an `A` subobject for the pointer to point to (or the reference to bind to, if you are casting to a reference type).

In your case, `e` is an `Editable`. There's no `ReadOnly` subobject anywhere in there. So the cast fails.

Comment: Thank you, so the problem was my misinterpretation of sideways casting. I will make `Editable` inherit from `ReadOnly` to gain the same functionality and eliminate `Base`.

Comment: @LogicStuff: If you go with that solution, you might change the name from `ReadOnly` to `Readable`, since an instance of `Editable` is clearly not something that is read only!

Answer (score 2):

You're not casting sideways.
You're casting from one derived of a base to another.

Let's hypothetically say your cast succeeded, and there's a public int member called `readOnlyInt` in `ReadOnly` class.

How can the compiler perform `readonly.readOnlyInt`?
There's no `readOnlyInt` in the casted `ReadOnly &` cause it is in fact an `Editable`.

Casting sideways involves multiple inheritance structures & looks something like this:

```
class A {
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B {
    virtual ~B() {}
};

class C : public A, public B {
};

int main() {
    B *b = new C();
    A *a = dymanic_cast<A *>(b);

    return 0;
}
```